# Set Normal angle with Geometry Nodes set smooth node

Tags: normals, geometry-nodes

In Geometry Nodes I am able to build curve based shapes by joining curves together with Join Geo, filling the curve then using a solidify modifier and bevel to create an extrude. However the resulting geometry can't use auto smooth. I have added a set smooth in the node tree, and this is good for smoothing say a circle but then you can't harden as per angle.

[image]

Comment: Stupid question: Why don't you use *Curve to Mesh* with a circle and a profile to achieve the result shown here?

Answer (score 3):

the set smooth node needs a calcul to works perfectly
[image: Set smooth]

Answer (score 2):

Use *Curve to Mesh* and a Profile Curve to solve this ...maybe.

[image]
[image]